# GET request but not getting results in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on a web app and I had the chance to render a table on my view from a database. After that I performed an ID request so I could click on a result on my table and render a view to see that line detailed.

The thing is: everything works fine, no error message is displayed and using dev tools from chrome I can see the json with the data is retrieved but the line where the reuslts should print, just don't show up.
My controller is as follows:

```
app.controller("ListaID",function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8000/organite/listagem/'+$routeParams.id).success(function(data){
        console.log($routeParams.id);
        $scope.obito = data;
    }).error(function(){
        alert("Ocorreu um erro inesperado!");
    });
});
```

And the app.js is:

```
var app = angular.module("organite", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/organite', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .when('/organite/tables', {
            controller: 'Lista',
            templateUrl: 'tables.html'
        })
        .when('/organite/tables/:id', {
            controller: 'ListaID',
            templateUrl: 'tableID.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/organite'
        });
});
```

The view is:

```
<div class="tables">
    <h3 class="title1">Vista detalhada</h3>
    <div class="bs-example widget-shadow" data-example-id="hoverable-table">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Número Sequencial</th>
                    <th>Anotações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{obito.NUM_SEQUENCIAL}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JSON is:

```
[{"URG_OBITO":1111,"NUM_SEQUENCIAL":1111,"NUM_PROCESSO":1111,"DTA_OBITO":"1111","HORA_OBITO":1111,"FALECEU_HOSP":"S","COD_ESPECIALIDADE":1111,"HSA":"1","NUM_EPISODIO":1111,"COD_MODULO":"1111","FSMS":1,"FEMAIL":1,"DSMS":"1111","DEMAIL":"1111","DTA_REGISTO":"1111","DES_ESPECIALIDADE":"1111"}]
```

(I changed the values to "1111" on purpose)

Comment: can you update your json response structure ?

Comment: you should use data-ng-repeat when you are dealing with json and I Hope you binded controller to the Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My updated view:

```
<div class="tables">
    <h3 class="title1">Vista detalhada</h3>
    <div class="bs-example widget-shadow" data-example-id="hoverable-table">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Número Sequencial</th>
                    <th>Anotações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="x in obito">{{x.NUM_SEQUENCIAL}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `data.data` when response comes

```
$scope.obito = data.data;
```

Comment: Somehow my JSON is an array (even though it only gets one answer) and I need ``ng-repeat`` to show my results. 

Thank you ;)

Comment: data.data is helped you?

Comment: Then I got back to ``$scope.obito = data;`` but used ``ng-repeat`` in my view. And it now shows the results ;)